# AWS ECS Tasks disappear directly after running them

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I try to run a Docker Image in AWS ECS. When I run a Task it says Pending, then when I press the refresh button the task is no longer listed, it's completely gone. What is the cause of this?

I expected the status of the task to go from Pending to Running. I have tried to make sure there is enough memory for the task to run, and that there is no permission missing.

Comment: Change the UI to show "ALL" tasks, not just running tasks. It sounds like your task if failing or crashing for some reason, and is transitioning directly to "STOPPED" state. The UI doesn't show stopped tasks by default, you have to change the filter to show them.

Comment: Welcome in SO. Please, provide as much details as possible. Namely include exact steps you made (do you use AWS console or awscli or ...). Can you share the docker image you use? Or at least the Dockerfile for this image? The more information you provide, the better answer you will get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default view is `Running tasks`; Change that to either `All Tasks` or `Stopped tasks`

[image: Running Tasks]